# mysql php echo values not appearing

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement and update query that updates a record in the database. I'm new to php here is my code :

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=  $name ?> "><br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" ><br><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?=  $pass ?>" >
```

Here is the fetch command:

```
   <?php
include("connection.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$qry = "SELECT * from studentinformation WHERE ID = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $name= $row['FullName'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $pass = $row['Password'];
            $major = $row['major'];
    }

?>
```

here is the action page:

```
    <?php 
include("connection.php");
//include("UpdateStudent.php");
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $email= $GET['email'];
        $pass = $_GET['password'];
      //$major = $_POST['major'];

      $qry = "UPDATE studentinformation SET FullName = '$name', email='$email', Password= '$pass'
      WHERE ID = $id";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
      if($result === false){
          echo "Record didn't update";
      }
      else{
          echo "Record Updated";
      }

    ?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="UpdateStudentAction.php?id=<?=  $id ?>" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Please help guys I'm new to php

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by '_echo values not appearing_'? Are your `Record didn't update` or `Record Updated` messages not appearing? Or something else?

Comment: both doesn't work echo not appearing and record doesn't get updated

Comment: `<?= $var ?>`  this is the echo

Comment: So currently you it returns this `echo "Record didn't update";`?

Comment: no it returns an error

Comment: in the query i think

Comment: sometimes undefined id in the form action

Comment: can someone link me similar questions ?

Comment: Move ID as a hidden field into your form, instead of GET parameter. Currently, this id ` $_GET['id']` is not passed, so your query fails.

Comment: also the values doesn't appear in the form neither of them appear

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: GET in C:\wamp64\www\Student\UpdateStudentAction.php on line 6
Record Updated this is the output

Comment: `$email= $GET['email'];`

Comment: @MoustafaAsaad, it must be  `$email = $_GET['email'];`, you have missed the undeline into `$GET`.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: loooooooooool XD

Comment: its for a class

Comment: i said im new man

Comment: @MoustafaAsaad I assume these comments are aimed at me. None of that stops you from learning to do it the best and most secure way. Get into good habits **now**, then you won't have to re-learn everything later when you come to write code for a "real" situation. It's not really any more difficult to write the queries safely, you can do it np. Your class tutor should be helping you with security stuff anyway, to be honest. If they aren't, then they are not teaching you properly. It's pretty much the most important thing to pay attention to in web development, unless you enjoy being hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `id` from action attribute into a hidden input:

```
<form action="UpdateStudentAction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
    ...
```

will do the magic.

And avoid empty spaces into `value` attributes;

Comment: choose the answer which covers best your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your form `POST` data instead of using `GET` method (that passes form data through url). Especially that you already using id query param in the url. You can include the id inside the form as a hidden field:

```
<form action="UpdateStudentAction.php?id=<?=  $id ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=  $id ?> ">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=  $name ?> "><br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" ><br><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?=  $pass ?>" >
</form>
```

Then in your `UpdateStudentAction.php` file you can receive data using post:

```
    <?php 
include("connection.php");
//include("UpdateStudent.php");
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
      //$major = $_POST['major'];

      $qry = "UPDATE studentinformation SET FullName = '$name', email='$email', Password= '$pass'
      WHERE ID = $id";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
      if($result === false){
          echo "Record didn't update";
      }
      else{
          echo "Record Updated";
      }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The GET method is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
2. The POST method does not have any restriction on data size to be sent. (You can use POST method instead of GET method)